# Laravel - PasswordController::getToken() does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

I'm making a password reset in Laravel 5.2 but I have 2 problems.

**1)** After the user gives in his email, the view from getSent doesn't get show, it just refreshes the email page.

**2)** When I click the link in the email, I receive this error

> Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController::getToken() does
>   not exist

Here's the code of my **passwordController**, I'm not sure if this is enough to help me, so let me know if you need any other code.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use View;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function getSent()
    {
        return View::make('auth.passwordSent');
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here are my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'csrf']], function () {

    Route::get('/password/reset/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

    Route::get('/password/reset/sent', 'Auth\PasswordController@getSent');

    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getToken');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
});
```

Comment: Well, I don't see a `getToken` method in there?

Comment: can you show us your routes please

Comment: Your routes should map `/password/token` to something. [According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords), laravel can create the password reset automatically by running `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: @zorx I added the routes in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is `getSent` should be `getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse` because this is the the method in the trait, which you can override:

```
public function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse()
{
    return View::make('auth.passwordSent');
}
```

The second problem is your routes map to methods that don't exist. Instead of `getToken`, you should be using `showResetForm`:

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
```

If you look in Illuminate\Routing\Router.php you will see that the correct password reset routes look like:

```
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

You can implement these in your routes.php simply by:

```
Route::auth();
```

Comment: Hi, great response this worked. However I was trying to find the route for when you succesfully reset the password, I think the fucntion name is "getResetSuccessResponse" however I can find the Rounting folder you directed to. Where can I find this or which route I use? thanks alot for your response!

Comment: I can't seem to get the succes right. After I reset the password. it refreshes the password/reset/{token} page and gives me the error. "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php" I can't find a route for it in the Illuminate\Routing\Router.php file either?

Comment: Yes I have     public function getResetSuccessResponse()
    {
        return View::make('auth.resetSuccess');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but this is a solution a colleague of me used with nearly the same problem.

Change the following code in your routes.php

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

to

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Hope this will work, I didn't test if ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I see here.

First, you mention that you're using Laravel 5.2, but the auth routing you're showing is from Laravel 5.1. Is this a project you upgraded from 5.1?

Second, from Laravel 5.1 (and looking into the `ResetsPasswords` trait), the controller method you should be using is `getReset`, not `getToken`.

Third, if you're on Laravel >= 5.2.27, you will want to remove the `web` middleware from your group, as it is already added by default to all routes in the routes file.